# Filtering through multiple parameters with array.filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of `people`  that I want to be able to search based of of their name. I have this working with the following code

```
{peopleArray
        .filter((people) => {
          if (
            people.name.includes(searchParams)     
          ) 
         
  
          {
            return true;
          }


          return false;
        })
 .map((people) => (
//map the data here
```

I have an input that sets the value of what the user types in to be set to `searchParams` This is all working fine, however I want to have 2 inputs and to be able to search by both `name` and `occupation`

So I made another input to be set with `jobSearchParams` and updated my filter function like this

```
{peopleArray
        .filter((people) => {
          if (
            people.name.includes(searchParams)   || people.occupation.includes(jobSearchParams)
          ) 
         
  
          {
            return true;
          }


          return false;
        })
```

However the second filtering doesn't work at all. When the second input has a value the array does not change at all. I have `console.log()`'d to show that the input is passing the value to `jobSearchParam` but still the array does not change.

 For more info, the peopleArray looks like this

```
{
name: "Bob",
occupation: ["builder", "developer"]
}
```

The searchBox values are set at the inputs like so

```
 <input className="nameSearch"
      placeholder="Search by Job" 
      value={jobSearchParam}
      onInput={(e ) => setJobSearchParam(e.target.value)}
      />
```

Comment: Add your search box values, code and sample  peopleArray  JSON

Comment: More info has been added

Comment: `let filteredArray = peopleArray.filter(person =>  person.name.includes(searchParams) || person.occupation.includes(jobSearchParams));
`. you can solve this in a single line of code

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult for me to read your example but I created something which does what you describe:

```js
var people = [
    { name: "John Citizen", occupation: "Developer" },
  { name: "April O'Neill", occupation: "Teacher" }
];

search = function(name, job) {
    return people.filter(person => {
    return person.name.includes(name) || person.occupation.includes(job);
  });
};

var resultBoth = search("John", "Teacher");
var resultJohn = search("John", "Dev");
var resultTeach = search("Nonsense", "Teach");

console.log(resultBoth);
console.log(resultJohn);
console.log(resultTeach);
```

It is possible that just your parameters are not right, remember that it will be case-sensitive, which you can fix by calling toLower on your person.name before the includes check.

UPDATE:
Modified to cater for an array of occupations per person:

```js
var people = [
  { name: "John Citizen", occupations: ["Developer", "Event Organiser"] },
  { name: "April O'Neill", occupations: ["Teacher", "Event Organiser"] }
];

search = function(name, job) {
  return people.filter(person => {
    return person.name.includes(name) || person.occupations.some(occupation => occupation.includes(job));
  });
};

var eventOrganisers = search("John", "Event");
var developers = search(null, "Develop")

console.log(eventOrganisers);
console.log(developers);
```

Comment: My parameters are correct, I've tested that. It will console.log exactly what I type in, and I manually set the `occupation: a` and typed in `a` and it still didn't match. I'm using a filter before a .map() could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Remove the map function, log the result of the filter itself. If you like the results of the filter, then you can see what's going wrong with your map function.

Comment: It looks like it is the filter. Does it have anything to do with my `occupation` being an array?

Comment: You can use the includes method on an array but you will require complete values, as in the cat ('cat' versus 'at') example here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

If you require to match on partial values you can just use a filter again on the values in the array.

Comment: @imstupidpleasehelp I have updated my original answer to cater for arrays of occupations, allowing partial search terms (still case sensitive, mind you)

Comment: After a lot of debugging I've figured out that the filter is working as intended. However it is only filtering when the `name` has value. So it will show the object with the proper occupation but it will not filter out the ones that do not have it until I type something in the nameSearch box

Answer (score 0):

You can get your search result this way.

```
const peopleArray = [
    { name: "Will Smith", occupation: ["builder", "developer"] },
    { name: "John Smith", occupation: ["Programmer", "developer"] },
    { name: "Katy Perry", occupation: ["Singer", "Programmer"] }
];

const getSearchResult = (nameSearch, jobSearchParams) => {
    return peopleArray.filter((person) => { 
        return person.name.includes(nameSearch) || person.occupation.includes(jobSearchParams) 
    });
}

console.log(getSearchResult("XYZ", "Singer")) // get single result
console.log(getSearchResult("Smith", "Singer")) // get multiple result
```